# Why forums database are not in 3rd NF?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forum

I was taking a look at some important forums such as SMF Forums, PhpBB, or VBulleting ones and i realized they are not in 3rd FN.

They have many NULL fiels, for example, in an SMF forum a member row can have all of this columns to NULL:

`pm_ignore_list, messageLabels, personalText, websiteTitle, websiteUrl, location, ICQ, AIM,` `YIM, MSN, timeFormat, userTitle, notifyAnnouncements, secretQuestion, secretAnswer, validation_code, additionalGroups, smileySet`

So... lets say 18 fields which can be NULL in any ROW of the table.
That's not 3rd NF...

Why they do it? I am sure they know much about BD...
Thanks.

Comment: for what reason should they require something to be inserted in those empty fields?

Comment: 3NF requires no nulls in non-key fields? Per Bill Kent: "[Every] non-key [attribute] must provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key." The null does that here.

Comment: @JonathanM: 1NF requires no nulls, depending on whose definition of 1NF you accept.

Comment: @Hajo, those fields are considered "optional" ones. The member can have them at NULL or with some data.

JonathanM, 3rd NF avoid empty fields in many cases and this is one of them. If you do it you would have many tables for each of the optional fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number one reason for denormalization is performance, which is a notorious problem with many discussion forums.

Originally SQL was not designed to store hierarchical data easily, and there are many less-than optimal schema designs trying to work around this limitation.

Comment: Yep, I agree and I want to add an example. You want to keep the last poster of the forum. You can do this easily by keeping only the ID of the last poster but if you do it like that than you need to make one more join when you are listing the forums or topics. If you want more performance, you simply keep the name of the user and ID together in the forums table which is now redundant but avoids extra join.

Comment: OK, i get it. Thanks RedFilter. So it's all about performance... then,  3FN is not always good at performance right?

Comment: Not always. *"normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works"*

Answer (score 1):

One or more of these reasons might apply.

- The database wasn't "designed" at all; it gradually accumulated more and more columns as any programmer who worked on it decided to add one. (Programmers are often only minimally trained in database design.)
- The "design", such as it is, is the result of committee decisions. (See above.)
- The "design" was known to be not the best idea, but was implemented in order to get the software to ship. The underlying fantasy is usually to fix it properly before the next release. (Often never gets fixed.)
- The table was denormalized for faster SELECT performance. In my experience, though, SELECT speed usually suffers more from a) the overuse of ID numbers and b) misunderstanding  normalization than from high degrees of normalization.